# How does the memory release for big return values (such as string) happen in C++?

Tags: c++, string, memory-management, return-value, return-value-optimization

Let's say I have a function A() in C++ and it calls another function B().
B() opens a file and reads a longish string and then returns this string to A(). Than A() uses this string as an input parameter to C(). C() is expecting a reference to a string.

For that I see two solutions:

1. B() gets a reference to a string as an *input parameter* (call it str). B() edits str and so A() gets the string. Releasing the allocated memory is the responsibility of A(). When A() is done using the string, it gives the memory back to the system. This is clear to me.
2. B() *returns* a string. I'm confused about this option. Who releases the allocated memory then? B() creates a local string, therefore can't return its address. B() has to return the parameter by value. As far as I know, thanks to return value optimization, not an actual copy of the string is created. In the background, parameter is still passed by reference. When I write pseudo something like that:

> ```
> A() {
>   C(B(filename))
> }
> ```

What happens than with the allocated memory? B() gets the filename, opens the file, allocates a memory block for the string it reads from file and then returns this string. This is the end of B()'s scope of life. A() doesn't have a variable defined to address this string. Who gives this memory block back?
And can I rely on RVO? Is it OK for the performance to return by value than? Does every compiler have it?

Comment: Return by value: Please read about return value optimization (copy elision) and rvalue-references.

Comment: @DieterLücking RVO is repeatedly mentioned in the question, so clearly OP is aware of it.

Comment: You don't need to worry whether or not the compiler supports RVO. Since C++11, move semantics (provided by rvalue references) guarantee that returning strings (or any object with a move constructor) is very efficient.

Comment: @Ferrucio Tnahk you, RVO part is clear now. 
How about releasing the memory? In Java I would depend on garbage collector and say if noone is using this data, garbage collector will take care of it. But what happens in C++?

Comment: @lulijeta: that's the responsibility of the object in question.

Comment: @lulijeta: In C++, the predominant paradigm is [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization). `std::string` follows this, so the memory is freed when the `std::string` object that used it goes out of scope (or is otherwise destroyed).

Comment: Objects with automatic storage duration (i.e. objects *not* created with `new`) are automatically destroyed, and the memory required to store them is managed by the compiler.

Comment: @greyfade what if I am not programming in an object oriented sense? C++ isn't pure object oriented like Java.
@JasonR So you mean, in this example, when A() goes out of scope, the allocated memory block is freed. And if A() is the main function, then it's just bad programming practice.
@BenjaminLindley What if I create a `char*` and allocate the memory for that in B() using `new`? Then I return it as a string?
Sorry for asking about the edges but my point is not to solve something at the moment, I am trying to understand the principle

Comment: It's not an edge case. your `string B(char *)` will actually be `void B(string &, char *)`. `string` is allocated on the caller's stack as per my answer, the function constructs it using `string::string(char *)` and returns. Then you'll probably have a memory leak if you don't clear the original `char *`.

Comment: @lulijeta: (by *"return it as a string"*, I assume you mean `std::string`?) The `char*` itself is handled by the compiler. And the string that is constructed from the `char*` in the return statement is also handled by the compiler.  But the memory you allocated with `new` is not handled by the compiler. You will have a memory leak if you do something like this: `std::string B() { char* p = new char[10]; return p; }`

Comment: @lulijeta: It doesn't matter - values in C++ are effectively objects that have lifetimes. It helps to think of it that way. The fact that C++ is not pure OO is meaningless. Nevertheless, values that are not fundamental types (like instances of the `std::string` class) have copy/move constructors and destructors that take care of the task of cleaning up the memory they use.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley and @Blindy I mean a std::string, yes. From what I understand, the 2nd option I thought would cause a memory leak. Because if I read from a file, I need to allocate the memory for the data like `char* buffer = new char[size]` Then since my return value is a string, I will return my buffer. When I return it, the scope of the function is over and I can't give any memory back. Therefore memory leak. Is it possible to read from a file inside of `string B(string filename)`, then return it as a string and meanwhile not cause a memory leak?

Comment: @lulijeta: Yes, you have a memory leak in that case. But it has nothing to do with returning a string by value. It is only because you used `new` without an associated `delete`. As for the question at the end of your comment, yes. It's certainly possible. But that question probably belongs in a separate post, rather than the comment section of this post.

Comment: Use `getline()` to read from a file stream into a `string` directly and bypass the silly intermediate objects.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I think I should think like C then. I could for example malloc (or allocate using new) some memory for a buffer in B() and return the pointer as a return value of B() and then free (or delete) in A().
As long as I don't lose the pointer adressing the memory I allocated using new, I can (and should) free the memory.
But is it really clean code when I release the memory in another function?

Comment: @lulijeta: No, you should not do that. In fact, you can, and probably should, completely avoid manual memory allocation altogether. There is certainly no need for `new` or `malloc` in the task you describe. Like I said, ask another question if you want to know how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Whether or not RVO is used is an optimization, and a transparent one at that. I'll cover that at the end because it makes no difference to the mechanics of returning objects by value.

Now when you return an object by value, what the compiler actually does is it adds an invisible parameter as a pointer. This memory is allocated on the caller's stack. Your function does its thing with the code as written (remember, no RVO), then returns the object which calls the copy constructor on the caller's object using the local one. Then the local one gets destroyed.

Who clears the caller object? Same as every other object, it follows RAII rules: its destructor is called when the scope ends, and the stack pointer rewinds past it when the function ends.

Now about RVO. All RVO does is it avoids the internal creation+copy+desctructor calls in the function -- it works directly with the object outside the function. It will call the proper constructor on it (think placement `new`), it will then use its fields and functions to do the work and at the end there's nothing left to do. It won't get destroyed or freed because that's the result -- and it's already in the caller's hands.

Edit: As to how common RVO is, any sane PC compiler supports it. It's as supported as `#pragma once`, despite the oddball purist who always comes to say how it's not 'standard'.

Comment: Oddball purist here: The standard specifies RVO ("compilers may elide copying/moving a return value") in 14882:1999 §12.8.15, and expands it in 14882:2011 §12.8.31-32 to include move elision.

Comment: "may" implies permission, not enforcement. Maybe I'm misreading your point, what is it?

Comment: My point is that the permission to implement RVO has been in the standard from the beginning, and after 16 years, it may be assumed that most, if not all, compilers implement it with rare exceptions.

Comment: Which is exactly what I said. I'm confused why you brought it up but we're in agreement here so yay!

Comment: I think the confusion is that your original "oddball purist" remark was, if I understand correctly, directed at those who might say `#pragma once` is not standard. But greyfade interpreted it as being directed at people who might (incorrectly) say that RVO is not standard.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming RVO is used, for your code:

```
A() {
  C(B(filename))
}
```

The compiler creates a temporary of type `std::string` in the context of `A`. It basically passes a hidden reference to that temporary when it calls `B`. `B` writes to the referenced string, then returns.

Then that temporary object is passed to `C`. So, the final code ends up roughly equivalent to something on this order:

```
// string B(); is turned into:
void B(string &ret) { 
    ret = "a really long string";
}

void A() { 
    {
        std::string temporary_object;

        B(temporary_object);
        C(temporary_object);
    }
}
```

I've added an extra block around the expansion of the expression to emphasize the fact that the temporary object is created as the expression `C(B(filename))` starts execution, and is destroyed again at the end of the expression.

What I've shown above differs from the real thing in a few respects. For example, if you have a class that doesn't support default construction, it'll still work, even when RVO gets involved (where the code above requires that the type be default constructible, which is fine for `std::string`, but might not work so well for anything else). If you want to be a bit more accurate, you'd probably pass a pointer to raw memory, and `B` would use placement new to create the return value in-place(but nothing you can show in C++ precisely duplicates what the compiler does).